# Div will not move down or to right

Tags: html, css

I had this working then I changed something. No matter what I do (and I've tried everything), i cannot get the showTable div to move down or right. It just stays anchored to the top. The html shows valid. Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Agent QC Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link href="static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="header">
        <p id="title">PNR File Finish</p>
    </div>
    <div id="leftside">
        <form>
            <label for="comp_name">Company:</label><br/> <input id="comp_name" type="text" value="" size="30" maxlength="50"/><br/><br/>
            <label for="nick">Company Code:</label><br/> <input id="nick" type="text" value="" size="4" maxlength="4"/><br/><br/>
            <label for="clientID">ClientID:</label><br/> <input id="clientID" type="text" value="" size="10" maxlength="10"/><br/><br/>
            <label for="recloc">Record Loc:</label><br/> <input id="recloc" type="text" value=""  size="10" maxlength="6"/><br/><br/>
        </form>
            <p id="info">Please be sure Client Name and Client ID are correct before running File Finishing!</p>
            <button id="shwTbl"  class="btn btn-primary btn-md active">Run File Finish</button>
            <hr>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md active">Reload PNR</a><br/><br/>
            <p id="info2">If Customer information is incorrect, reload underlying PNR</p>
    </div>
        <div id="showTable">

        </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/start.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the css:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}

.container{
    width: 1200px;
    height: 800px;
    backround-color: #FAEBD7;
}

#header{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: darkblue;
}

#title{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#leftside{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: 550px;
    border: 1px solid darkblue;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#info{
    color: darkred;
}

#info2{
    color: darkred;
}

#showTable {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 100px;


}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The margin-top and margin-left are working. What's the problem/where should it go?

Comment: There's probably more CSS that you did not include that is causing something going wrong. The html/css you provided looks fine to me.

Comment: The "showTable" div will not move down no matter what I do.

Comment: It is using an Ajax call inside the div, but that should not make a difference. I had is working but then changed something and could not get it working again.

Comment: I copied your code into CodePen and it is working fine? Are you sure everything is being included correctly.

Comment: What is it you have changed? Try undoing it and change it again step by step, to find out where you messed it up. If not, try to reproduce your error in a JSFiddle or CodePen so that we can check it out

Comment: here's what it looks like. It's not working in xampp https://travlintom-outlook.tinytake.com/sf/MTM1NDI5Ml80OTU4NjQ5

Comment: Was able to fix issue. Had to do a reinstall of xampp and it worked. Thanks for your help.